# Need a customizable wait method for visibility and selectability of an element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need a method where I can change time to wait for a certain criteria as per my requirement in selenium

Comment: So write it. If you are stuck in ***specific*** place, come back and ask about it,

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will, firstly it will check whether Element is available in back-end or not, if element is available in back-end then it will wait till element display.(if element is not available in back-end then also it will wait till element is in back-end)

```
public void E_WaitUntilElementDisplay() throws Exception
{

    int i=1;
    boolean eleche,eleche1 = false; 
    while(i<=1)
    {
            try{
                eleche = driver.findElements(By.id("ABC")).size()!=0;
            }catch(InvalidSelectorException ISExcep)
            {
                eleche = false;
            }
            if(eleche == true)
            {

                while(i<=1)
                {
                    try{
                        eleche1=driver.findElement(By.id("ABC")).isDisplayed();
                    }catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException NSEE){
                        eleche1=false;
                    }
                    if(eleche1 == true)
                    {
                        i=2;
                        System.out.println("\nElement Displayed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i=1;
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                        System.out.println("\nWaiting for element, to display.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                i=1;
                Thread.sleep(1500);
                System.out.println("\nWaiting for element, to display.");
            }
    }
}
```